# laravel eloquent orm - limit columns in eager loading query?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to do a eager loading query of a table that has a one-to-many to another table.

So initially, I'm doing this:

```
    $node = $this->MapNodes()->where('type_id', $typeId )->with('NodeCounters')->first();
```

This works, but the problem is that table on the far side of the relationship has a LOT of columns, which really bloats the result.  If I only need a couple of columns, is there a way I can limit/specify the table columns retrieved on the far side of the relationship?

Comment: i guess MapNodes() is you property Method in that case you can chain select() clause to it and specify the names of column you want to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put constrains on your relationships.

```
$node = $this->MapNodes()->where('type_id', $typeId )
                         ->with( ['NodeCounters' => function($query){
                                 $query->get(['column-1', 'column-2']);
                         }])
                         ->first();
```

Check the official [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: Ah!  You can use a get()-with-columns in the with() function just like using where(), like the docs show.  Nice!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it

```
$node = $this->MapNodes()->where('type_id', $typeId )
->with('NodeCounters:id,column-1,column-2')->first();
```

From this doc: [Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)